# Displaying a MessageBox over a DialogForm causing a weird UI glitch

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, devexpress

I've got a button on my form, and when it's clicked it does the following:

```
private void btnCheckSVN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wait = new DevExpress.Utils.WaitDialogForm("Fetching File SVN Status", 
                                               "Please Wait");
    wait.AutoSize = true;
    wait.Visible = false;
    bgwSVN.RunWorkerAsync();
    wait.ShowDialog();
}
private void bgwSVN_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = svn.SvnStatusEventArgsToDataTable(svn.CheckSVN(_localPath));
}

private void bgwSVn_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)e.Result;
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = "File ASC";
    gdcSVN.DataSource = dt;
    gdcSVNDefaultView.BestFitColumns();
    xtcTabs.SelectedTabPageIndex = 1;
    lblTotalFileCount.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        XtraMessageBox.Show("No files found.", 
                            "Error",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    wait.Close();
}
```

With this order of operations, you can (obviously) still see the Wait Dialog behind the `MessageBox` and it just looks really sloppy in my opinion.

If I switch the IF statement and the `Close()` call, my `WaitDialogForm` half-disappears for lack of a better term. There's an empty rectangle with a red frame and a giant X going through it, then the `MessageBox` on top of that as its own form.

This is my first time messing around with any sort of multithreading or using the `BackgroundWorker` objects at all, so I'm sure I'm just missing something really stupid but I don't know what?

I tried completely removing the `MessageBox` from this event, and instead doing this:

```
 wait.Close();
 lblTotalFileCount.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
```

Then handling the label's TextChanged event and checking to see if it should display the MessageBox then... but I still get the same results with the red box.

**Edit**; Also, a weird thing I noticed. On form load, lblTotalFileCount was set to 0. When this method runs and say it found 0 files, it would re-set lblTotalFileCount.Text to zero... Which did *not* trigger the TextChanged event? I understand that it was being set to the same thing it already is, but it was still technically changed. Am I missing something, or does the event actually check for that condition and "skip" it if that's the case? I had to just set the label to be an empty string instead... But say they run the application, it gets set to 0, alerts them, they make some changes, run it again... still 0, it won't alert them.

**Edit 2**; I thought maybe if I tried calling wait.Close() in the TextChanged event for the label as mentioned in my first edit *before* the MessageBox shows up, maybe it'd work? Nope. Same Problem. And then if I click the button a second time, the form crashes because wait has been disposed? It's a form level property why would it get disposed?

**Edit 3**; Well, if I call wait.Dispose in the TextChanged event, I get the desired behavior. Except it minimizes the main application and just shows me the MessageBox unless there's nothing behind it. Son of a...

Comment: Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.  The debugger will now stop when the Paint event handler throws an exception.  You'll probably need help from Infragistics support to make sense of the call stack.  Good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but it doesn't throw an exception with any of the variations of code I've mentioned with that enabled.

Comment: It does.  That's why you get the red cross.  Just look in the Output window, you'll see the "first chance exception" debugger notification.

Comment: First, make absolutely sure `RunWorkerCompleted` is executing on the UI thread. It should be in your case, but there are scenarios where it won't especially if you did something really wacky when you instantiated it (unlikely). If it isn't on the UI thread then that might explain the problem. Otherwise, the big red X is generally symptomatic of a problem with the control.

Comment: HansPassant Just tried again with the Output window open... A ton of stuff gets thrown in there when I first launch the application, but nothing gets added when I click the button or close the MessageBox.

BrianGideon How would I check for that?

Comment: Compare the output of `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` both inside `btnCheckSVN_Click` and `bgwSVn_RunWorkerCompleted`. They should be the same. Also, if you drug the `BackgroundWorker` onto your form from the toolbox then I can almost guarantee that `RunWorkerCompleted` is on the UI thread already.

Comment: Yep. They're on the same thread.

I think I saw on their forum somewhere saying the WaitDialogForm is an "unsupported" control and usually used internally. So perhaps you were right, it's just a weird nuance with the control itself?

Only using this for an internal tool so it doesn't need to be pristine. Guess I'll just have the MessageBox display over the dialog. Sadface.

Comment: Did you try calling wait.Dispose() in bgwSVn_RunWorkerCompleted before you showing the XtraMessageBox ?

Comment: @sgmoore see my third edit in the original post. If I call Dispose on the wait form then it minimizes the rest of my application for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls. To modify a winform or a control from another thread (BackgroundWorker does that) you should make this call from the main thread. In this question you have your answer: [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)